hyperlink to a cell uing todays date as a reference. r.g. todays date is 05/feb/2024 move to cell that week begining 01/Feb/2024
I have a spreadsheet that has a column containing week beginnings e.g. Week beginning (wk-beg) o2-Feb-24 Cell B3, B4 is wk-Beg. 09-02-24 etc. for 52 weeks of the year, how do I click a hyperlink so tat it takes me to the cell that is relevant to todays date 9=Today() in say cell A5
I can not get a hyperlink to do this.
